# Laravel 8 - How to add items on list with relationship

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have 3 relational tables Cart, CartProducts and Products and in the query I have the low JSON result, but I want to add the product name and description information in cart_products.
Relationships:
Cart with CartProduct

```php
public function cartProducts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CartProduct::class);
}
```

CartProduct with Product:

```php
public function products()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

And the query:

```php
$data = Cart::with(['cartProducts'])->where('user_id', '=', $id)->orderBy('id')->get();
```

```json
[
  {
   "id": 1,
   "user_id": 4,
   "amount": 55,
   "cart_products": [
     {
      "id": 1,
      "cart_id": 1,
      "product_id": 6,
      "price": 7.8,
      "quantity": 1
     },
     {
      "id": 3,
      "cart_id": 1,
      "product_id": 5,
      "price": 66,
      "quantity": 5
     }
    ]
  }
]
```

and this is the result I want

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 4,
    "amount": 55,
    "cart_products": [
     {
      "id": 1,
      "cart_id": 1,
      "product_id": 6,
      "name": "Product a"
      "price": 7.8,
      "quantity": 1
     },
     {
      "id": 3,
      "cart_id": 1,
      "product_id": 5,
      "name": "Product b"
      "price": 66,
      "quantity": 5
     }
  }
]

Tables
Cart: id|user_id|amount
--------------------------------------------------
CartProduct: id|cart_id|product_id|price|quantity

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDSRb.png
```

Comment: Where are product *name* and *description* come from?

Comment: It comes from product, example: in blade it would be cartProduct->product->name, but I don't know how to do that in json.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) and append it to your CartProduct model.

```
class CartProduct
{
    protected $appends=[
        'product_name'
    ];

    public function getProductNameAttribute()
    {
       return $this->product->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: That means you have an item in your cart which is not related to a product. BTW, you can use `optional()` method to skip it. `return optional($this->product)->name`

Comment: "product_name": null, But in cart_product table has the FK (image above)

Comment: Solved, I added the 'product_id' pivot here $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id'); and I hid products that was showing up too. Thank you very much for your help.